# can't update an account if i'm not an admin on my page no real errors but it skips the if

Tags: php, sql

for some reason if a user is logged in and he is not an admin, the code will skip the execute if statement right before the query's and right after the echo $admin; and I can't seem to figure out why. who can help me solve this?
and when I'm logged in as an admin it runs perfect no problems at all.
the admin is stored in the database as a 1 and normal users are stored as a 0

this is my code:

```
<?php
session_start();
//server gegevens
$server     = "localhost";
$user_sql   = "root";
$wachtwoord = "";

//maakt verbinding met de database                                         geeft een foutmelding als het verbinden niet is gelukt
$connect = mysql_connect($server, $user_sql, $wachtwoord) or die("couldn't connect to server please try again later");

//selectreert de database
mysql_select_db("camping") or die("DB not found");

$Admin      = "";
$Knummer    = "";
$voornaam   = "";
$achternaam = "";
$Tussen     = "";
$username   = "";
$email      = "";
$Reg        = "";
$Straat     = "";
$Hnummer    = "";
$woonplaats = "";
$Postcode   = "";
$Tel        = "";
$Pw         = "";

if (isset($_POST['hidden']))
    $Knummer = strip_tags($_POST['hidden']);

if (isset($_POST['Voornaam']))
    $voornaam = strip_tags($_POST['Voornaam']);

if (isset($_POST['Achternaam']))
    $achternaam = strip_tags($_POST['Achternaam']);

if (isset($_POST['Username']))
    $username = strip_tags($_POST['Username']);

if (isset($_POST['Woonplaats']))
    $Woonplaats = strip_tags($_POST['Woonplaats']);

if (isset($_POST['email']))
    $email = strip_tags($_POST['email']);

if (isset($_POST['Tel']))
    $Tel = strip_tags($_POST['Tel']);

if (isset($_POST['Straat']))
    $Straat = strip_tags($_POST['Straat']);

if (isset($_POST['Hnummer']))
    $Hnummer = strip_tags($_POST['Hnummer']);

if (isset($_POST['Postcode']))
    $Postcode = strip_tags($_POST['Postcode']);

if (isset($_POST['admin'])) {
    $Admin = strip_tags($_POST['admin']);
    /*this if is because on the admin pannel you can type yes/no to update the admin status of an user and in the database the admin is logged as 1/0 */
    if ($Admin == "yes") {
        $Admin = 1;
    } else if ($Admin == "no") {
        $Admin = 0;
    } else {
        $Admin = $Admin;
    }
}

if (isset($_POST['tussen']))
    $tussen = strip_tags($_POST['tussen']);
else
    $tussen = " ";

echo $Admin;

if ($Knummer && $voornaam && $achternaam && $username && $Woonplaats && $Straat && $email && $Tel && $Hnummer && $Postcode && $Admin) {
    $query  = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET admin='$Admin', Username='$username' 
                                WHERE Klant_NR='$Knummer';");
    $query2 = mysql_query("UPDATE klant_gegevens SET Voornaam='$voornaam',Tussenvoegsel='$tussen',Achternaam='$achternaam',Straat='$Straat',H_nummer='$Hnummer',Postcode='$Postcode',Woonplaats='$Woonplaats',email='$email',Telefoon='$Tel'
                                WHERE Klant_NR='$Knummer';");
    header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
} else {
    echo " **error/skip message**";
}

?>
```

Comment: There are a lot of if statements...which one gets skipped???

Comment: Which `if` is skiped when logged in as user? When `$_POST['admin']` is set to 'no', $Admin will be set to 0. `if($some_var && $Admin)` will evaluate to false in that case. So the branch won't be executed to unset the admin status of a user. Your question is very unclear and will be closed if you don't clarify your exact problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get '**error/skip message**' if '$Admin' is not set.

Set the error reporting level so that you get PHP errors if there is any.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Your code is not very well formatted and the fact that you have a long if condition makes for bad practice. It is best to set that as a function and loop through your input to find whether there is data in them or not. Once you use good coding standard, it will become very easy to debug and diagnose issues with your code.

http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Coding_conventions/PHP

Comment: thanks for the info i will work on it. and i dit not know that you could loop through the Post values. but thats maybe because this is the first site that i made. also because of one flag down in like 5 min and your answer and i went asking my self why it would have been like that and then it hit me its because non admin's have a value set as 0 and that is the problem >.> i was breaking my head over it the last 5 hours i have set all non admins users to 2 and its fixed best regeards

Comment: Glad I could help. Keep at it. Practice a lot.